# preg_replace() заменить только первый результат почему?

Tags: php

preg_replace() заменить только первый результат почему?

```
function filter($data) {
    $oldString = array('&#x1f600;','&#x1f603;','&#x1f604;');
    $newString = array('smile1','smile2','smile3');
    return str_replace($oldString, $newString, $data);
}
function smile($data) {
    $data = preg_replace_callback('/[\x{80}-\x{10FFFF}]/u', function ($m) {
        $char = current($m);
        $utf = iconv('UTF-8', 'UCS-4', $char);
        return sprintf("&#x%s;", ltrim(strtoupper(bin2hex($utf)), "0"));
    }, $data);
    preg_match_all("/(&#[a-zA-Z0-9]{6};)/", $data, $hashtweet);
    foreach ($hashtweet[1] as $ht){
        $data = preg_replace("/(&#[a-zA-Z0-9]{6};)/", filter(strtolower($ht)), $data);
    }
    $data = mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
    return $data;
}
echo smile('&#x1f600; &#x1f603; &#x1f604;');
```

---

Вот результат.

> smile1 smile1 smile1

---

Если заменить на `echo str_replace($oldString, $newString, $data);` то получаю такую результат. (Вообще неправильно)

> smile1smile2smile3

---

Как сделать такой результат

> smile1 smile2 smile3

**P.S.** Есть другой вариант?!

Comment: Не вижу проблемы. http://ideone.com/mUWTGH

Comment: @ReinRaus здравствуйте да, я знаю, самом деле `&#x1f600; &#x1f603; &#x1f604;` эти коды такой смайлы `   `

Comment: @ReinRaus например я напишу `Привет ` а этот код ищет смайлы и заменить на слов `Привет smile1`

Comment: Во входной строке которую надо обработать что находится ? unicode-символы или html-entites этих символов ?

Comment: @ReinRaus вот последний `mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');`

Comment: То есть на входе юникод-символы смайлов, а на выходе их названия вместо них? При этом список заменяемых смайлов предварительно определен?

Comment: @ReinRaus да названия вместо них и тоже есть список всех смайлов

Comment: Как по ссылке выше решает задачу? Я изменил пример кода. Или обязательно нужны промежуточные этапы и регулярные выражения?

Comment: @ReinRaus промежуточные этапы и регулярные выражения обязательно нужен а то мой другой коды не работает :(

Answer (score 2):

Так если они у вас точно соответствуют друг другу, зачем replace использовать? Может стоит создать ассоциативный массив вида ключ-значение, например:

```
$array = [];
$array['&#x1f600;'] = 'smile1';
```

И всё, потом значение `&#x1f600;` приходит в переменной `$code` например вы делаете `$array[$code]` и получаете `smile1`

Comment: Просто так написать? работает без return? Проверили?!

Comment: `function filter($data) {
    $array = [];
    $array['&#x1f600;'] = 'smile1';
    $array['&#x1f603;'] = 'smile2';
    $array['&#x1f604;'] = 'smile3';
    return $array[$data];
}` не работает и тоже `foreach ($hashtweet[1] as $ht){
        $array = [];
        $array['&#x1f600;'] = 'smile1';
        $array['&#x1f603;'] = 'smile2';
        $array['&#x1f604;'] = 'smile3';
        $data = preg_replace("/(&#[a-zA-Z0-9]{6};)", $array[strtolower($ht)], $data);
    }` не работает

Comment: `replace()` обязательно нужно потому что заменить только смайлы может быт такой значение `echo smile('Hello! &#x1f600; &#x1f603; &#x1f604;');` и получить `Hello! smile1 smile2 smile3`

Answer (score 2):

Нашел ответ сам с помощью `preg_replace_callback()`. Проблема была в `foreach()`

```
function filter($matches) {
    $oldString = array('&#x1f600;','&#x1f603;','&#x1f604;');
    $newString = array('smile1','smile2','smile3');
    return str_replace($oldString, $newString, $matches[1]);
}
function smile($data) {
    $data = preg_replace_callback('/[\x{80}-\x{10FFFF}]/u', function ($m) {
        $char = current($m);
        $utf = iconv('UTF-8', 'UCS-4', $char);
        return sprintf("&#x%s;", ltrim(strtoupper(bin2hex($utf)), "0"));
    }, $data);
    $data = preg_replace_callback('/(&#[a-zA-Z0-9]{6};)/', 'filter', $data);
    $data = mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
    return $data;
}
echo smile('&#x1f600; &#x1f603; &#x1f604;');
```

> smile1 smile2 smile3